# Trouble Adding Custom Tools to SSIS Toolbox in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis, bids

I'm using the SSIS Designer in Visual Studio 2010 and I recently downloaded a third-party suite of tools.  Their post-install steps say to navigate to *Tools > Choose Toolbox Items > SSIS Control Flow Items* and add their items to my SSIS Toolbox but my installation of Visual Studio is missing the *SSIS Control Flow Items* and *SSIS Data Flow Items* tabs.  The third-party says these tabs should be there and that this is a Microsoft issue.  Does anyone know how to make these tabs appear?  Is something misconfigured?

Comment: Yes, I am using SQL Server 2012 and the Integration Services and Data Tools that come with it.

Comment: Things are supposed to automagically show up in the SSIS toolbox for SSDT 2012. I have built out custom components and have not had an issue with it nor did I experience any issues with the CozyRoc 1.6? beta of their tools. Just to cover the obvious, the vendor has supplied a 2012 version of their product? The 2008 DLLs won't show up as the signature is different and the support they are providing is accurate for pre-2012 SSIS.

Comment: And we there we find the problem.  The third-party software isn't compatible with SQL Server 2012 until next week.  Thanks, billinkc.